# How to send alert from linux machine jboss server whether services are UP or Down in linux?

Tags: java, linux, api, jboss

I am running a web **API service** (java) which is in production on **jboss** server in **Linux** machine. Now my client wants an automated alert (email) every morning that the services are UP and running. How can i do this using linux?

Comment: How does he define Up and Running?

Comment: That's should be an alert email -  E.g. "Services are UP and Running" if the Jboss is running.

Comment: So the criteria is that Jboss is running. How would you detect if that’s the case?

Comment: That's the one way i think. What i wanted to know is how would i use the status of jboss to send an alert mail. in linux can we use like PID to know that any service is running or not? and then use that status for the same.

Comment: That is one way.  Another way could be writing a test client in your favorite language that invokes the web API and sees if it is successful, if not send a mail.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to suggest a monitoring tool